# Why should I ![enter image description here][1]?

Tags: support, images

![enter image description here][1]

What does the *image description here* affect? Does it ever show up somehow other than when I edit a post?

I put "yuk" there. So what?

[image: yuk]

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez sure. What should happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

«For the screen readers of visually impaired, for browsers that don't show images, for cases where Imgur is blocked, and for search engine indexes: please enter a good description.»

Comment: ahh. To all "visually impaired" and search engines, please accept my apology...I've gotta edit some old posts of mine...

Comment: Imgur is blocked on my computer... it is helpful when people add the "title" text.

Answer (score 7):

I once had a clever remark for a question.  (This was in a different stackexchange forum.)  It was mostly an image, so I posted it as an Answer.  But the software (or maybe a moderator) changed it to a Comment.  Now it no longer shows the image, just a link to the image together with the text "enter image description here", since I had not entered a description.

Answer (score 4):

Check the source code

```
<img alt="yuk" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMU8i.png"></img>
```

and see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute